# Is there any pattern like first up kafka brokers and then up the consumers ? or we can up anything dynamically

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using

kafka_image=wurstmeister/kafka
 zookeeper_version=3.4.14
kafka_version=2.12-2.4.0
 C# client: Confluent kafka v1.2.0

We are using 3 brokers , 1 zookeeper cluster.

Is there any pattern like first up kafka brokers and then up the consumers ? or we can up anything dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper must be running for brokers to start. Brokers must be running for clients to not error out with network exceptions.

Comment: Side note: confluentinc images along with the schema registry would be preferred with Confluent libraries that support Avro

Comment: Thanks for comment,

is there any official note from kafka, if yes can you please provide it,
coz for daily deployment we use to stop all services(zookeper,brokers,producers , and consumers) , later will start consumers first and then brokers,If there is a problem in order it should fail every time,my case only sometimes consumer got stuck

Comment: Zookeeper nor Brokers generally should never be stopped unless for maintenance. Feel free to read over the Apache Kafka & Zookeeper sites in your own time

Comment: We are using 3 brokers , 1 zookeeper cluster As a pat deployment we use to stop all the brokers ,zookeeper,producer,consumers and delete the kafka-log files, and starts consumers first later will starts the brokers and zookeeper. In this process some time consumer getting stuck, its not picking any messages even it alive. If i restarts the consumer, it started picking

Comment: As stated, brokers must be running before consumers. It doesn't matter if your topics are empty or don't exist yet. Basically there needs to be a healthy broker controller and consumer group leader for any consumer to work

Comment: Thanks for comment,
is there any official document for this pattern,if yes can you please give it.

Comment: As I said, feel free to read over Apache Kafka site on your own